# Find all entire functions that satisfy a given inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, entire-functions

Find all the entire functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy
$$
|f(z)|\leq |z|^5 + \frac{1}{|z|^5} + \frac{1}{|z-1|^3}.
$$

I proved, by using the Cauchy estimatives, that $f$ must be a polynomial of degree at most $5$. Also, if we write
$$
f(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + a_3z^3 + a_4z^4 + a_5z^5,
$$
it is easy to see that $|a_5|\leq 1$ (just divide both sides of the inequality by $|z|^5$ and let $z\to \infty$ on the Riemann sphere). But I'm still unable to give a complete characterization of all entire functions satisfying the given inequality.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's fairly easy to see that if $\lvert a_5\rvert = 1$, then one must have $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 0$. But for $\lvert a_5\rvert < 1$ it looks ugly. Where does that problem come from?

Comment: @DanielFischer this exercise was proposed in a complex analysis course I'm taking.

Comment: Is it using a specific book? (If so, maybe a search would turn up some information.)

Comment: We are using Conway's "Functions of one complex variable" and Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis" but I did not find any helpful information.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you tell me how to prove that $a_0=a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=0$ when $|a_5|=1$. I can't see it so clearly, but I was suspecting it.

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised that you didn't find anything helpful. I'll think a bit more about it, but I don't expect to find a complete characterisation. When you get a solution (or an "oops, doesn't work"), would you mind pinging me? // Concerning the $a_k = 0$, suppose (at least) one of the lower coefficients is $\neq 0$, let $m$ be the largest such index. Then there is an argument $\varphi$ such that for $z = r\cdot e^{i\varphi}$ you have $\lvert a_5 z^5 + a_m z^m\rvert = r^5 + \lvert a_m\rvert\cdot r^m$. Then let $r \to +\infty$ to see the inequality cannot hold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100440/discussion-between-albert-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: I'd be interested to see a clean solution to this. Could maybe hope to throw some snazzy inequalities at it from something like Levin or Rahman-Schmeisser, but nothing jumps out at me immediately

Comment: @DanielFischer: That argument works if $a_5=1$.  But $f(z) = \frac 12(z^5 + z^4)$ satisfies the inequality as well, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: ... or $f(z) = a_0  + \ldots a_5 z^5$ with $|a_0| + \ldots |a_5| \le 1$.

Comment: @MartinR That argument is only for the case $\lvert a_5\rvert = 1$. The case $\lvert a_5\rvert < 1$ looks ugly, as I said in my first comment. It's also easy to see that $f(z) = a_m z^m$ satisfies the inequality for $0 \leqslant m \leqslant 4$ and $\lvert a_m\rvert \leqslant C_m$ (but determining $C_m$ isn't easy, involves finding a zero of a $14^{\text{th}}$-degree polynomial). And since the family of entire functions satisfying the inequality is absolutely convex you have a bunch of inhomogeneous polynomials satisfying the inequality. The monomials $a_mz^m$ with $\lvert a_m\rvert = C_m$ are…

Comment: …extreme points of the family, but these are not all extreme points, so the family $\{ \lambda_0C_0 + \ldots + \lambda_5z^5 : \lvert\lambda_0\rvert + \ldots + \lvert \lambda_5\rvert \leqslant 1\}$ is a proper subset of the family of all polynomials satisfying the inequality.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oops, I missed your first comment and looked only at the third, sorry for that.

Comment: No problem, @MartinR. The elaboration it caused may be useful.

Comment: @Albert Did you get any feedback about this exercise yet in your course?

Comment: @DanielFischer No, I'm sorry. My teacher also got stuck.

Comment: Any further developments?